# Using pattern RegEx validation in ionic directly in HTML

Tags: angular, regex, ionic-framework

I am trying to validate forms in ionic using pattern validator. Now I have seen examples of ng-Pattern and pattern being directly used in HTML in web but I haven't seen such an implementation in ionic.

```
<input id="{{list.fieldName}}" type="text"
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="newUser[list.fieldName]"
        [maxlength]="maxlength[list.sequenceNo]"

        [pattern]="patternStatus[field.sequenceNo]"/>
```

While debugging, I can even see the pattern like this `pattern="/(^[0-9]{0,10}$)/"` (RegEx to validate numbers) in the HTML but its not validating.

Is there a way to do it directly in HTML or do I have to use Validators and FormControls?
By the way maxlength validation is working here.

Comment: Use the `pattern="[0-9]{0,10}"` pattern.

Comment: For Ionic I think you need to use <ion-input>. And after that apply patterns: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#pattern